# Trying to create a Composite Primary Key in MSSQL with only a part of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, composite-primary-key

I'm new to SQL and am following a course, however it does not cover the "create table" part.
It only covers statements etc.
What I would like to have is, my primary key (cust_id) to be generated with the "first_name" and the first 3 letters of "last_name".
*I.E. I want "John Smith" to become "custid"; JOHNSMI.*

I have below code which works (without composite).

```
CREATE TABLE NL_client (
    custid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (10000, 1),
    userid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    birthday DATE
);
```

And I found below code (last line added)

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE (
    custid INT,
    userid VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (first_name, last_name),
);
```

However, when trying to execte the second query as displayed above it does not create a Primary key. Or when I execure the below queries;

```
custid INT PRIMARY KEY (first_name, last_name),
```

Either above in the query or at the end, it does not make a primary key.

Furthermore, I have no idea, nor was I able to find *(perhaps I searched wrongly, surely I'm not the first with this "problem")* how to select only the first 3 letters of "last_name" to be used as a part of the "custid".
Perhaps this is not possible and I should use "custerid" as an INT Primary key and use "userid" as a composite.
But it would surely help me in the future to be able to use the Primary Key as a reference in Python.

Many thanks in advance for your help and let me learn to understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: The primary key is a constraint on the table. It doesn't create new columns, it enforces uniqueness on existing ones. If you want a new column that contains your value, use a computed column (e.g. `custid AS first_name + LEFT(last_name, 3) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY`). Do note that "first name plus first three letters of last name" is a pretty awful choice for a primary key: names are not unique, let alone parts of names combined, nor are they unchangeable -- this (among other reasons) is why putting the key on an identity column is generally a much better idea.

Comment: `Firstname, lastname` is a poor choice of key anyway: there may be many John Smiths, not to mention many John Smidt and John Smiddy. You probably want to take `birthday` as another column in the key

Comment: Many thans both! Luckily where I live there are no John Smith's :P. Was merely meant as an example. However, I will look into making the custid longer i.e. 4-5 letters of lastname.

In the end it will be a program that I control and use (estimated a max of 100 users), so in case of duplicates I can manually change the custid I would assume. Or perhaps go for unique keys and use the userid for futher reference, once I get the ID-lists once it all works and once I can go test with live data.

Comment: You could make the key `Firstname + Lastname` in its entirety and it still wouldn't do anything to guard against people with the same name. I should know: my name is not at all unique. I even know a Jeroen Mostert who studied at the same university. At best you could use a field like that as short mnemonic to search on even if it's not a key, but that could also be achieved by simply allowing name fields to be searchable (or allowing users to pick short aliases themselves if they haven't been taken, much like online services do).

Comment: Despite my natural stubborness I have to agree with you. Guess you are even my own nationality or even close to my country. Perhaps it is then better to just maintain unique keys as "10000" and onwards and approach the code in Python differnetly. Better safe than sorry I guess ;). Many thanks for your input!